# Teradata Update the Partition from Each Month to Each Day Interval

Tags: teradata, database-performance, database-partitioning

We were working on updating the partition in Teradata, and we did implement the partition. There are few tables for which partition have been created for interval of 1 month. Now, we have to update it and should have interval of 1 day. I would like to know the steps and syntax to update those partition. I did ask Teradata DBAs, but there wasn't much help available from them. I know it's easy to update if there are no data in the tables, but we have data for the partitions that were created for 1 month interval. What are the steps I can take to make sure there won't be no loss of data and data accuracy and consistencies remain intact.

Thanks!!

Comment: How big are the tables?  Can you just create a new table with the new partitioning and do an `INSERT/SELECT` from the old table?  You won't lose any data, they will just be stored in different partitions.

Comment: You can DROP the old monthly partitions and ADD the new daily partitions in the same ALTER TABLE, both with the same RANGE. All rows will be automatically moved to the new partitions. But this will use Transient Journal, thus performance might be bad.